# MySQL table outline not appearing when called from shell_exec in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, linux, bash

I'm trying to output a visual table of a MySQL result when I run a PHP program similar to the output if I had run the MySQL query straight from the command line. However, when I run the query through shell_exec it does not output the nice table lines around the data.

```
mysql DB_NAME -e "SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME;"

+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
| row1  | row2  | row3  | row4  | row5  | row6  |
+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
| data1 | data2 | data3 | data4 | data5 | data6 |
+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
```

PHP:

```
$output = shell_exec( "mysql DB_NAME -e \"SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME;\"" );
```

However the above PHP code won't output that table with the borders around it.

Let me know if I can clarify anything!

Comment: Just a shot in the dark .. Sometimes `exec` returns slightly different formatting that `shell_exec` -- Have you tried that?  --  To be honest, I don't know if the "last line" would be the entire table , or the last line of the formatting ..  It's just a though.

Comment: Just tried that.. unfortunately no luck. I think it has to do something with table formatting in the terminal... I just found if I redirect the output of the command line mysql command to a file, the table lines don't appear in the file either.

Comment: Doing this through `shell_exec` seems not only extremely risky, as if you're using variables in there you're opening yourself up in a huge way, but completely unnecessary. Why not do the same thing with PDO and some string formatting with [`sprintf`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php)? For a pre-existing solution, look on [Composer](https://getcomposer.org) for a text table layout tool.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the normal CLI behavior. The following is an excerpt from the [official documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-shell/8.0/en/mysql-shell-output-formats.html):

> If the `resultFormat` configuration option has not been specified, when MySQL Shell is in interactive mode, the default format for printing a result set is a formatted table, and when MySQL Shell is in batch mode, the default format for printing a result set is tab separated output.

## Addendum: how to change the default format

In the very same article, a few lines after the above, there is this paragraph:

> Alternatively, the command line option `--result-format` or its aliases (`--table`, `--tabbed`, `--vertical`) can be used at startup to specify the output format for a session.

Comment: That begs the question .. Is there a way to "fool" mysql into thinking it's in interactive CLI?

Answer (score 2):

Well my boss came in clutch and found the solution. Add a --table to the end of the mysql command and shell_exec (and any redirect file for that matter) will get the table outline formatting.

```
mysql DB_NAME -e "SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME;" --table
```

Thanks for everyone's help!